# Android 2d game engine that supports multi screen resolution

Tags: android, game-engine

I'm looking for an android 2d game engine, where you can create your game at the resolution you want, and the game will work the same on every phone, no matter the resolution, maybe by auto creating thoose black rectangles.

I was working with libGDX, but i could not find any ways to do that, just some viewport scalling methods, that will make the game graphics quality crappy.
I also used to work with the android sdk using surfaceview, and i had to code everything by a ratio, and also scale the bitmaps by a ratio, but i don't really think that that is a good way to do it.

Are there any android game engines that support every device resolutions?

Comment: Libgdx does support every devices resolution. Ofc you have to code something, that it does this. But this will be the same with every other game engine. They are not made to do everything for you, but to help you do your stuff.
The graphic quality may is "crappy" because you use the wrong method, and that is not the engines fault.
Do not forget, that if you use other engines you have to use the Android emulator, which is not that fast, instead ofdeveloping 99% on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for something you won't get. I doubt that there's a tool or engine released to the public that will automagically fix all resolutions possible to fit your needs. This is something that developers has to tackle, and it's a nice thing to handle independently.

Now when working in LibGdx, did you even try to use Texture filters? Linear filtering will smoothen your images when enlarged. They may get some blur but I've released a commercial game using this method.

All in all, i really think you should give it another shot. LibGdx will spare you a large amount of troubles and in my opinion; The request of yours ain't that hard to overtake.

Comment: Yea he tryed `Linear` filtering allready. I also suggested him to try mipmapping but it messed up everything. I think the reason is, that he has a `TexturePack`, not made with `TexturePacker`, and cuts out custom regions, based on pixels. But if you know more about this things feel free to look at the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429815/libgdx-textures-quality-on-different-phone-resolutions